# Problemas al restaurar una base en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Por error borre una tabla de mi base,previo tengo un backup,pero al querer restaurarlo me dice que la tabla no existe,necesito primero crearla? ya intente hacerla pero son muchos campos y no recuerdo con exactitud los campos,tengo otra tabla igual en otra compu pero como exporto la pura estructura de la base para asi poder crearla y depues restaurarla?

Comment: Es raro que el backup no incluya la estructura de la tabla? pero como te indican si tienes una tabla igual puedas hacer `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombre_tabla` para optener una consulta para generar la estructura

Answer (score 1):

Con `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombredelatabla` te da el código para crear la tabla en la otra base

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html